# Is rescinding reputation on a bountied question allowed?

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, bounties

I looked under "bountied" questions on Stack Overflow on 25-Aug and found [How should I create an algorithm for the centroid of any System.Windows.Media.Geometry object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1324544) offering 100 reputation points for an answer.

I offered an answer and went back and forth with updates to clarify and offer additional information.

After providing the answer, receiving a comment from the original poster that "This looks like an awesome solution, and it's basically the road I want to take", I find that the original offer of 100 reputation points is no longer in evidence.  I got an up vote for the answer, but it hasn't been accepted.

Is it kosher to offer reputation points and then rescind the offer?  Or is the "bountied" question working in a way that I've failed to grok yet?

I probably would have answered anyway, because I'm interested in the problem, but it seems misleading.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I award bounty to a helpful, but incomplete, answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367785/should-i-award-bounty-to-a-helpful-but-incomplete-answer) - had it been answered it would say that the awarder can choose to do whatever they want, even make decisions which seem unfair; subject to the limits imposed by automatic awarding of the bounty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the bounty expired, the top vote getter is automatically set as the accepted answer, unless there is no answer that gets at least +2 overall score. Once bounties have been placed, they cannot be rescinded by the original poster, but they can expire and not give any reputation (and even the OP will lose his rep in the process, it is not refunded.)

Comment: Thanks to both of you.  I didn't realize that's how it worked.  Your explanations sorted it out for me, but I can only accept one.

Comment: Glad that sorted it out for you.  Too bad you gave the reputation to the guy who already has 13.4k! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that the bounty has expired?  Either way, you receiving the reputation depends on the asking party marking your answer as accepted, while the bounty is in effect.