# Should I award bounty to a helpful, but incomplete, answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, bounties

I raised a bounty of 100 rep on a fundamental yet non-trivial question on the [mathematics Stack Exhange site](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour). One genius guy answered the question; however, the answer was *incomplete*. Using those ideas, I developed my own simpler solution.

I am facing a dilemma here. Should I award the bounty to the answer? It has only one upvote (by me). The guy does deserve the bounty. However, if awarded, the future visitors might perceive the answer as perfect, which is not good for the community in long term.

Note: I can not accept my own answer since the question is not mine. It was posted by someone else a few years back and had no good answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I award bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70650/282094) or https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243405/282094

Comment: There [are two](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) [mathematics sites](https://mathoverflow.net/tour). Do you mean *[Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour)*?

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q Yes.

Comment: You should feel no obligation to award the bounty to a specific answer yourself.  If you are pressured to do that you should flag those comments immediately

Comment: @Ramhound Nobody is pressurizing me. It is just that the guy who gave the answer deserved that. Unfortunately, his answer is incomplete. :(

Comment: If the answer is incomplete then the author doesn’t deserve anything, even if the answer was complete, the author of the answer doesn’t deserve anything.  Author is welcome to edit their answer and make it complete at any time, right?

Comment: @Ramhound Yeah...you are also right.